# Inkscape: why do coordinates in GUI and XML differ?

Tags: inkscape, svg, xml

In the drawing below I have e.g., a rectangle.

[image: screenshot showing coordinates in GUI and XML]

In the GUI, Inkscape says the rectangle is at Y position 0, but in the XML for that element it says 873. Why is that and how do I get the "real" number?

Background: When exporting the image (scripted), I want to add 10 pixels border on all four sides. I thought I could just look for the largest / smallest coordinates in XML and add the 10 pixels for border, but I end up exporting an all white background instead of the image. Working with the XML comes natural here because I get other (meta) information from that.

I can query the image origin with `inkscape -X` and `inkscape -Y` and the image dimensions with `inkscape -H` and `inkscape -W`. That also gets me the numbers from the GUI. Exporting with these values works. However, that requires forking a new Inkscape process 4 times per image, and hence slows the whole export down. (Lots of images on old hardware.)

This is Inkscape 0.91 on Linux, in case that matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually SVG units are expressed in **pixel**, and if Inkscape coordinates are set to pixel, they should coincide (see also [here](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Units_In_Inkscape) and [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Coordinates.html)).

In your example the difference in width (236.185 vs 234.869) and height (180.000 vs 178.6805) is due to the **border width** of the rectangle, which is included in Inkscape W and H and not included in SVG width and height.

For example, with a border stroke of 1 px:

[image: rectangle with a border]

The same rectangle without a border:

[image: rectangle without a border]

Note that the border is centered on the path. In my example we have:

Inkscape W = SVG width (199px) + half stroke left (0.5px) + half stroke right (0.5px) = 200 px

[image: the stroke is centered on the path]

Be aware that the **Y coordinate** in Inkscape has the zero on the bottom of the document, while in SVG the zero is on the top of the document.

Y = 0 in Inkscape means an object at the bottom of the document:

[image: Y=0 in Inkscape]

Y = 0 in SVG means an object at the top of the document:

[image: Y=o in SVG]

This means that your "real" number is something like:

Y coordinate in SVG (px) = Page height (px) - Y coordinate in Inkscape (px) - Object and borders height (px)

(Note that the inversion of the Y axis will be fixed at some time in the future according to this [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170049).)